# Select max value of timestamp grouped by name, jobId and Action

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have my table as shown below(in the upper part of the image), I want to select the `max timestamp` of the job performed by a `user`. For example, `User1` performed many `Process1` activities and we need to select the latest activity which is `Start` for `Process1` on `5.11.2020`.

I can not use the `group by` as I would ahve to include all the column names in `select` and `group by` which would just get all the coumns as the timestamp is unique per employee.

How can I achive this?

Sample Data:

```
| User  | Activity | Timestamp       | Action |
|-------|----------|-----------------|--------|
| User1 | process1 | 1.11.2020 10:00 | Start  |
| User1 | process1 | 1.11.2020 10:30 | Stop   |
| User1 | process1 | 1.11.2020 11:00 | Start  |
| User1 | process1 | 1.11.2020 11:30 | Start  |
| User1 | process1 | 5.11.2020 10:00 | Start  |
| User2 | process1 | 5.11.2020 10:05 | Start  |
| User2 | process1 | 5.11.2020 10:30 | Stop   |
| User2 | process2 | 5.11.2020 10:45 | Start  |
```

The output should be:

```
| User  | Activity | LastAction |
|-------|----------|------------|
| User1 | process1 | Start      |
| User2 | process1 | Stop       |
| User2 | process2 | Start      |
```

Comment: Please provide consumable DB structure and example data when asking a question. Screenshots are not very helpful. Furthermore please provide info on what you have tried so far! However, have a look on window functions (e.g. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY... ORDER BY...)` - this should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to identify the latest row per user and activity:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by user, activity order by timestamp desc) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```